# In Flutter, how to make each Row child as big as the biggest child?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-layout, flutter-row

I am trying to find a way to have two `ListView` as children of a `Row` **to have matching heights**. This means if one `ListView` is shorter than the other one, then it must stretch until it matches the other `ListView`'s height.

Schematically speaking this is what I have now:

[image: schema]

**How can I have the green `ListView` to match the orange's `ListView`'s height?**

This is my row at the moment:

```
Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      _buildList(list: listA), // returns a `ListView` wrapped in `Card`
      _buildList(list: listB),        
    ],
  )
```

I tried setting `crossAxisAlignment` to `CrossAxisAlignment.strech` but it causes an error with this message:

> A RenderBox object must have an explicit size before it can be hit-tested. Make sure that the RenderBox in question sets its size during layout.

I believe it means that one of the child can't ascertain its height...

Comment: Are you referring the background color ?

Comment: `IntrinsicHeight` maybe?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh no I am not referring to the background color. The color is just to help read the schema. In my project, the `ListView`s are wrapped in a material `Card` so it's clearly visible that both lists aren't of the same height.

Comment: Can you test below snippet and share your feedback, that snippet tested inside scaffold body

Comment: @pskink I have read on SO that it could be a solution but the documentation strongly advise against it because it's expansive. Where are you suggesting to use it ? On the `Row` itself or on each child (`ListView`) ?

Comment: check https://youtu.be/aqraU67ms4g or https://youtu.be/ce07f8ClcMQ  or similar short intros

Comment: @pskink thanks, the second video was very good and straight to the point! However it does not seem to work with `ListView`s as I am getting this error: "RenderViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions." I have previously tried with `shrinkWrap:true` but then I got the same error except it was for a "RenderShrinkWrappingViewport". I think using `ListView` in my situation is wrong. Working with `Column` instead seems to do the trick though.

Comment: @pskink so yeah, works fine with `Column`. Thank you very much for your solution. If you provide an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: your welcome, write a self answer then :-)

Comment: i think you need create list with shinkwrap true, and set list 2 itemExtent height = List 1 height/ List 2 item count

Comment: @cloudpham93 how can I know the actual height of either of my list? In one case, List 1 can be bigger than List 2 and in another case, it's the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your `ListView` with `Expanded` widget

```dart
_buildList({required List<String> list}) {
  return Expanded(
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.cyanAccent,
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
          title: Text(list[index]),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image]

Also provide `ScrollController` to listview to avoid getting error

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried reproducing your example but I think it does not quite get the result I expect: indeed both `ListView` are now of the same height, however they both seem to stretch to the whole screen. My aim is to have them as short as possible and of the same height. Also, what does `ScrollController` have to do with the error I got? Can you elaborate on that, thanks !

Comment: While you have multiple scrollable widgets, it will provide an error on console like single controller attached to multiple widget.

Comment: You can try `IntrinsicHeight` as pskink mentioned  but it is expensive

Answer (score 1):

After following [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73420134/in-flutter-how-to-make-each-row-child-as-big-as-the-biggest-child/73428004#comment129657902_73420134) suggestion to use `IntrisictHeight`, albeit very expensive as per the documentation, I managed to make it work by replacing my `ListView`s with `Column`s.

Indeed, as my list are quite short (as explained in my OP), there is no need for `ListView` with scrolls, animation, recycling, etc.

Using `Column` was also the only way to make it work with `IntrisictHeight` anyway.

**So this is the solution I retained:**

```
IntrinsicHeight(
    child: Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        _buildList(listA),
        _buildList(listB),
    ],
),

Widget _buildList(List<String> list) {
    return Container(
        width: 400,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
        child: Card(
          elevation: 10,
          child: Column(
           mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
           children: [
             _SkillType(name: skillType),
             for (final Text in list) Text(text),
          ],
       ),
    );
}
```

All thanks go to pskink.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List<String> listData = List.generate(10, (index) => '$index');
  List<String> listData2 = List.generate(5, (index) => '$index');

  List<TextEditingController> listDataCTL = [];

  ScrollController controler = new ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('AppBar'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Flexible(
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    controller: controler,
                    itemCount: listData.length,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemExtent: (listData.length < listData2.length) ? listData2.length / listData.length * 50 : 50,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Container(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
                        child: Text('Item'),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    controller: controler,
                    itemCount: listData2.length,
                    itemExtent: (listData.length > listData2.length) ? listData.length / listData2.length * 50 : 50,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
                        color: Colors.red,
                        child: Text('Item'),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

**When listData.length> listData2.length**
[image]

**When listData2.length> listData.length**
[image]

**UPDATE:**

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('AppBar'),
      ),
      body: Card(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            _buildList(list: listData, compareList: listData2),
            _buildList(list: listData2, compareList: listData),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )



 _buildList({List<String> list, List<String> compareList, double itemExtent = 50, double spacing = 8}) {
    return Flexible(
      child: GridView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: list.length,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 1,
          crossAxisSpacing: 0,
          mainAxisSpacing:
              (list.length < compareList.length) ? (((compareList.length - list.length) * itemExtent) + ((compareList.length - 1) * spacing)) / 4 : spacing,
          mainAxisExtent: itemExtent,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.3 + ((index * 5) / 100)),
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
            child: Text('Item'),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

I think you want this version:

```
_buildList({List<String> list, List<String> compareList, double itemExtent = 50, double spacing = 8}) {
    return Flexible(
      child: Card(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: list.length,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: (list.length < compareList.length) ? (((compareList.length - list.length) * itemExtent) + ((compareList.length - 1) * 0)) : 0,
          ),
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemExtent: itemExtent,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              color: Colors.red.withOpacity((index * 5) / 100),
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
              child: Text('Item'),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution that seems way cheaper than using `IntrisictHeight`, however using `itemExtent` here would be problematic because it makes the children size differently which I don't want to. Also, in my specific case I am using a `Card` as parent for the lists. I wanted both `Card`s in the `Row` to have the same height for perfect symmetry.

Comment: @Mackovich Try new update

Comment: @Mackovich try last update